# Intercept URL links like "https://myApp.com/xyz" "not myapp://xyz"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I'm wondering if its possible in ionic/cordova to intercept URL links so that links which could open in the browser, could be intercepted an opened with my app. For example clicking an https://www.youtube.com link will open in the Youtube app. I know theres a plugin available to open them using a custom url scheme such as myApp://xyz but that's not what I'm asking about here.

Comment: This plugin will do what you want: https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin

Answer (score 0):

@mohamed,
your asking for an [`activity`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html), which tells the (Android) system your App provides a service. This is opposed to an [`intent`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html), which is used to tell the system you "intend" on using a service.

Cordova Repository Plugin is here http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/

I am not sure how to search for this.
This maybe one of the only advantages that "native" apps have over hybrid. Check with [Eddy Verbruggen](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen). He might now.

Jesse